# Weakest reduction for P-completeness

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

It is common to define $P$-completeness with respect to logspace many-one reductions. I am looking for a complexity class $C$ such that if $C=P$ then all problems in $P$ are $P$-complete under many-one $C$-reductions.

> What is the weakest many-one reduction (computable in class $C$) for which the class of P-complete problems remains unchanged?

Note that $C$ is contained in $P$.

Comment: I don't understand your intro. $\mathrm{P}$ is closed under polytime reductions so, for _any_ $\mathrm{C}$, $\mathrm{C=P}$ implies that every [non-trivial] problem in $\mathrm{P}$ is $\mathrm{P}$-complete under $\mathrm{C}$-reductions.

Answer (score 1):

There is [first-order reductions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_reduction).

See [Immerman's book, Chapter 3, Theorem 3.26](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~immerman/book/ch3.pdf) which states that $\mathrm{REACH}_a$ **is complete for** $\mathrm{P}$ **via first-order reductions**.

Also, see my [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/96859/weakest-reduction-for-3-mathrmsat), for related information on $\mathrm{NP}$.

Comment: Note that Immerman assumes a rather rich first-order setting that can do bit arithmetic and so on.

Comment: Yes, it seems that weak reduction for $\mathrm{P}$-completeness is more cumbersome. $\mathrm{FO}+\mathrm{BIT}$ is known to capture uniform-$\mathrm{ACC}^0$, which in turn, has not yet been separated from $\mathrm{NC}^1$. See [Lautemann et al.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.35.6051&rep=rep1&type=pdf).